# Query more than 10,000 records from salesforce using C#

Tags: soap-api, integration

I'm trying to collect data from Salesforce (from a custom object). I referenced generated Enterprise WSDL from Salesforce and referenced it to my web application.

I am pulling data from Salesforce and storing in a database, but only see 2,000 records.

Is there a way to pull more than 10,000 records from salesforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QueryResult` returned from `client.query` will have a `queryLocator` property and have the `done` attribute set to `false` if there are more records to return. You can use the `queryLocator` value in a `client.queryMore` to retrieve the next batch of records. You will need to continuously call `client.queryMore` until `done` is `true`. See [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sample_query_calls.htm) for more information. They have an actual example written in C# that you can start from.

---

```
public void querySample() 
{
    try
    {
        QueryResult qr = null;
        binding.QueryOptionsValue = new sforce.QueryOptions();
        binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 250;
        binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = true;

        qr = binding.query("SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact");

        bool done = false;
        int loopCount = 0;
        while (!done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nRecords in results set " + 
                Convert.ToString(loopCount++)
                    + " - ");
            // Process the query results
            for (int i = 0; i < qr.records.Length; i++)
            {
                sforce.sObject con = qr.records[i];
                string fName = con.Any[0].InnerText;
                string lName = con.Any[1].InnerText;
                if (fName == null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + lName);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Contact " + (i + 1) + ": " + fName
                        + " " + lName);
            }

            if (qr.done)
                done = true;
            else
                qr = binding.queryMore(qr.queryLocator);
        }
    }
    catch (SoapException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message +
            " Stack trace: " + e.StackTrace);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery execution completed.");
}
```